# File Unique Id of Revit, CAD file

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

We are wanted to get the Unique Id from the project information using forge API, as we do in revit using the code snippet below.

---

UIApplication app = commandData.Application;                                                Document doc = app.ActiveUIDocument.Document;                                                       ProjectInfo pi = doc.ProjectInformation;
var ID  = pi.UniqueId;

Answer (score 0):

Revit's UniqueID commonly appears in the object property's external id in Forge Viewer. So, we can get it from the property of the project information element, but it's not the File Unique Id.

- Queried by Revit Lookup

[image]

- In Forge Viewer

```js
viewer.search('Revit Project Information', dbIds => dbIds.forEach(dbId => viewer.getProperties(dbId, console.log)), null, ['Category'],  { searchHidden: true })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped. I had one more can we access FingerPrintGUID(This property can be accessed using AutoCAD) by anyway using the Forge API

Comment: Hi @VeereshHuvinahalli, my colleague has replied to you here. Unfortunately, the answers is no at this moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441429/can-we-access-fingerprintguid-for-drawing-filedwg-using-forge