# Can we access FingerprintGUID for drawing file(dwg) using forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, forge

How can access **FingerprintGUID** using forge api as we can fetch it using Autocad **Database.FingerprintGuid**

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible at the moment, I have taken a note of this request.